# Device Font Size overriding font size of the application

Tags: android, fonts, device

After changing the device fonts, the font of the application is also getting changed, This is happeing in Sony Xperia S, I have set the the textsize as `15 dp`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: should not override if you set the unit as dp? is it sp?

Answer (score 0):

you may use font size in `sp` like `15sp`

Comment: i tired all both sp and dp. The problem when i create view in run time and set text . it is picking device font size.